# Exposing DAO's (in Struts2 based apps.) through WS

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws, hibernate-generic-dao

How can i design a Web Services which will expose already developed hibernate entity classes in Struts2 base application? 
Third party application is to do CRUD operation,how can i use the same Hibernate classes to do the CRUD through web services?

Comment: why you want to mix Data access layer with Struts2? use any service layer to hide inner implementations

Comment: Actually I need to use hibernate entities which i have already implemented for Struts2 based application.I want to use the same in webservices.

Comment: that is perfectly fine, all i am asking is not to expose your DAO layer directly to the Struts2 actions and use some kind of service layer to hide internal implimentation

Comment: Can you give some suggestion what kind of service layer should i use?